# Java window pop-up issue

Tags: java, popup, jframe

The code works like this:

When input a number, some modifications to img1 will be done, and the modified img1 will pop-up. Then enter another number, the new modified img1 will pop-up.

The problem is when the new modified img1 pop-up, the old one will not close. So after I enter 5 numbers, there will be 5 windows open.

How can I modify the code so when a new window appear, the old one will close?

```
while(true){
    System.out.println("Choose a frame: ");     
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    if (a>12){
            break;
        }

  //some modifications to img1 here


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel lblimage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img1));
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblimage, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(848, 480);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create the instance of the JFrame you are using outside of this while loop. (or maybe the method/function containing it. So, as you call the method, you're not creating a JFrame object, you can just be modifying one that is already existent.)

If you insist on creating a new JFrame over and over again you can implement this to close JFrame windows:

```
        frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

This will act as if you have closed the window out.

Comment: I added it before the line"JLabel lblimage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img1));" and it did not work, did I add it to the right place?

Comment: @SamW try creating the JFrame object outside of this method, so when you get to setting the content of it in the method, you're just modifying an object that already exists. It looks like after that loop you're making a JFrame all over again. (I'm assuming this is all in a method that you call multiple times) Let me know if that works. With that said, I don't think you'd have to end up closing the window.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this:

```
JFrame frame = null;
while(true){
    if(frame != null){
        frame.dispose();
    }
    ...
    frame = new JFrame();
    ...      
}
```

With this could you should only ever have one instance of a `JFrame`.

Comment: This is simple, but inefficient because you're constantly going to be initializing and disposing of your instance and its subcontrols inside that JFrame in the memory. Then you're requiring the rebuild of them, instead of just changing the properties of them.